# How to remove stuck filter module

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture, bathroom-fixtures

The following video shows the replacement part, and then the precise manner in which the part is stuck. I'm told that it could be the calcium deposits or the part might be broken. Any suggestions on getting it out? (Really hoping to avoid a plumbing company coming out).

https://i.imgur.com/TgPjmFD.mp4

UPDATE - the module is OUT! There's an 80% chance that it was what @crip659 said. But there's a 20% chance that it was thanks to this rubber glove contraption that I made that allowed me in inject vinegar into that chamber. The part came out intact. The back o-ring had come off so maybe it was a combination of the o-ring and calcium build-up that kept it in.

[image]

Comment: Think it is just catching on something.  I would give it a gentle pull, and turn constantly, till you feel it give.  Might have a groove in it that you need to line up.

Comment: See if the other one comes out more easily and pay close attention to how it feels when it comes out.  That might give you a better sense of how much force to apply to the stuck one, and where.   Also it looks like there's a set screw [there](https://imgur.com/a/MObopPV).  What is that?   The part where you'd insert a wrench seems to be blocked.  Can you figure that out?

Comment: I'm guessing here, but I think the second O ring on the back of the module has dislodged slightly and possibly has calcium deposits requiring a little extra elbow grease to remove.

Comment: @crip659 and HoneyDo - I think you were both right! Pls see my edits.

Comment: @jay613 The set screw is an alternative way of mounting the overall valve. As far as the other module, it's 100% stuck and the Allen wrench socket is stripped. Any suggestions on how to deal with that side? (Is it worth a separate post?)